# Vue sorting numbers

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sorting

I have vue data:

```
data: {
          offices: requestData,
          selectedFloors: [
            "3",
            "4",
            "5",
            "10",
            "11",
            "12",
          ],
          minJobAngle: 0,
          maxJobAngle: 80,
          minAreaAngle: 0,
          maxAreaAngle: 900
        }
```

And I need to use **selected floors** for filtering table rows. Filtering works fine but the order of selected floors in the filter is 10, 11, 12, 3, 4, 5

I have this function in my methods

```
getFilteredOffices() {
            const areaMin = this.sliderAreaMin;
            const areaMax = this.sliderAreaMax;
            const jobsMin = this.sliderJobMin;
            const jobsMax = this.sliderJobMax;
            const floors = this.selectedFloors;
            return this.offices.filter(function (item) {

              if (item.acf.suurus < areaMin || item.acf.suurus > areaMax) {
                return false;
              }
              if (item.acf.tookohad < jobsMin || item.acf.tookohad > jobsMax) {
                return false;
              }
              if (!floors.includes(item.acf.floor)) {
                return false;
              }
              return true;
            });
          }
```

This under computed

```
    getAvailableFloors() {
            const set = new Set();

            const sorted = this.offices.sort((a, b) => {
              if (a.acf.floor > b.acf.floor) {
                return 1;
              }
              if (a.acf.floor < b.acf.floor) {
                return -1;
              }
              return 0;
            });

            sorted.forEach((office) => {
              set.add(office.acf.floor);
            });

            return set;
          },
```

And this is my html

```
<label :class="['checkbox-label floor' + item]" v-for="item in this.getAvailableFloors">
   <input type="checkbox" name="floor" :value="item" v-model="selectedFloors"> @{{ item }}
   <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Any idea what I am missing and how I get these floors displayed like this 3,4,5,10,11,12?

Comment: `this.offices.sort((a, b) => a.acf.floor - b.acf.floor)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing strings instead of numbers. String  `10`, `11`, `12` are lower than `2` or `3`. Use `parseInt` to convert the string before comparing.

```js
getAvailableFloors() {
  const set = new Set();

  const sorted = this.offices.sort((a, b) => {
    if (parseInt(a.acf.floor) > parseInt(b.acf.floor)) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (parseInt(a.acf.floor) < parseInt(b.acf.floor)) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  });

  sorted.forEach((office) => {
    set.add(office.acf.floor);
  });

  return set;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to cast your floors to numbers using `Number('3')` for example. This will make the comparisons between numbers and not between strings.

When you are comparing strings you will get alphabetical soring (lexicographic ordering) in which for example `10 < 2`.

Here is the fixed sort function:

```
 const sorted = this.offices.sort((a, b) => {
      const floorA = Number(a.acf.floor);
      const floorB = Number(b.acf.floor);
          
      if (floorA > floorB) {
           return 1;
      }
      
      if (floorA < floorB) {
          return -1;
      }

      return 0;
 });
```

To read more about type casting see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_Conversion